# Is there a way to manage repetitive image path in fxml?

Tags: java, url, javafx, path, fxml

I'm wondering what is the better way to mangage path in my fxml file ?
For example, I have many fxml files with  :

Is there a way to store `/ressources/images/` somewhere and do something like this :

```
<Image url="@MY_DEFINE_PATH/success_128.png" />
```

where `MY_DEFINE_PATH` come from a global file somewhere in my project ?

Comment: `@` locations are relative to the fxml file.

Comment: Not sure but maybe using some fx:define?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès How can I set my define with a variable somewhere outside the current package ? And it means set a new fx:define in every fxml file ?

Comment: See [Location Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution) and [`fx:constant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements)

Comment: @Itai I think this is the good way to do it. But how can I concat two strings with fxml (I don't think this is possible) Because I can do something like this : 
`<Image><url><Settings fx:constant="IMG_PATH"/></url></Image>` but this won't allow me to append the name of my image. Infos :`public static final String IMG_PATH = "/ressources/images/";` and my image name `success_128.png`

Comment: You can "import" the constant into FXML with `<fx:define><Settings fx:id="imgPath" fx:constant="IMG_PATH"/></fx:define>` (just once in the FXML file), and then do `<Image url="${imgPath+'success_128.png'}"/>`

Comment: @James_D Thank you but I don't know why, javafx doesn't like {}. This is working `<Image url="$imgPath"/>` This is NOT working : `<Image url="${imgPath}"/>`
Error : javafx.fxml.LoadException: Cannot bind to untyped object.

Comment: Ah... that's right. You can't use expression binding for constructor arguments (only for actual properties). That's... annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed your own DTD entity definition:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE GridPane [
    <!ENTITY imgPath "/ressources/images/">
]>
<GridPane>
...
<Image url="&imgPath;success_128.png" />
```

You could also link to an external DTD, but then one should use an **XML catalog** (DTDs in local cache mapping from their URLs) to speed up processing of the XML.

---

***Using an external DTD file***

```
<!DOCTYPE GridPane [
    <!ENTITY imgPath "/mypaths.dtd">
]>
```

mypaths.dtd:

```
<!ENTITY imgPath "/ressources/images/">
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I get "/ressources/images" from a variable outisde the fxml file ?

Comment: For a _static_ configuration, an external DTD could be used (- I extended the answer). **If you mean something in java:** either go by id attribute, or add a custom attribute with your own namespace, and iterate in code through the Images.